# How to find the java process that is using a port

Tags: macos, network-programming

I have a small Java ServerSocket application that is running on port 4444. I wanted to see the process using that port in my OSX terminal, and my first thought was to do the following:

`netstat -a | grep 4444` however, this doesn't give me any results.

`lsof -i :4444` and I get the following (correct) result:

```
COMMAND   PID        USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    66389 admin   18u  IPv6 0x1ae123a422ebe931      0t0  TCP *:krb524 (LISTEN)
```

Could someone tell me why netstat doesn't show the port but lsof does?

Answer (score 2):

Netstat probably does list your task, but with an alias 'krb524' instead of the port number.  Those aliases are listed in `/etc/services`.

```
$ grep 4444 /etc/services
krb524          4444/udp    # KRB524
krb524          4444/tcp    # KRB524
```

To see just port numbers with netstat, add the `-n` parameter.

```
netstat -a -n | grep 4444
```

Comment: Interesting - do you know why it uses an alias?

Comment: I can't get inside the heads of the netstat authors, but I think there was a feeling that humans would prefer nice string descriptions for things running instead of numbers.  http://tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-iface.netstat.html  Since the invention of netstat, there has been an explosion of "well known" services, so it makes it hard for developers to choose a port that isn't already registered in `/etc/services`, making that symbolic display less useful than it might have once been.